# Show different content on each category in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom category.php file in my template. I want to show a unique banner on each category. How do I do that? I am new in Wordpress Developing and I have no idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this really old [forum post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/category-banners), which pretty much just says use the [`is_category()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category)

```
if(is_category(9))
{
    //show come banner
}
else if(is_category(10))
{
    //show another banner
}
else
{
    //show default banner
}

?>
```

Comment: What if I have 1000 categories? Lol, is there a better way? I found a plugin which inserts a custom field in the categories add page, but I do not know how to call that value. The plugin can be found here:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/categorycustomfields/